# Adjacancy matrix for a square lattice in C++

Tags: c++, lattice, adjacency-matrix, complex-networks

I am trying to write a code in C++ for calculating the adjacency matrix for a N by N square lattice graph, i.e a graph in which all (i,j) nodes are connected with (i+1,j),(i-1,j),(i,j-1), and (i,j+1) nodes.

I tried the following code, that works only for a 2 by 2 lattice, but it doesn't for higher orders. Can anyone help me on how to make this code appropriate for finding the adjacency matrix for an N by N square lattice?

Any help is really appreciated.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <cmath> 
using namespace std;
int vertArr[20][20]; //the adjacency matrix initially 0
int count = 0;
void displayMatrix(int v) {
   int i, j;
   for(i = 0; i < v; i++) {
      for(j = 0; j < v; j++) {
         cout << vertArr[i][j] << " ";
      }
      cout << endl;
   }
}
void add_edge(int u, int v) {       //function to add edge into the matrix
   vertArr[u][v] = 1;
   vertArr[v][u] = 1;
}
main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   int N= 2;
   int v =pow(N,2);    //there are N^2 vertices in the N by N graph

   int ii;
   for(ii=0; ii<v; ii++){
     add_edge(ii, ii+1);
     add_edge(ii, ii-1);
     add_edge(ii, ii+N);
     add_edge(ii, ii-N);
   }
   displayMatrix(v);
}
```

Comment: Your main problem is caused by you hard coding adding the edges in the for loop in main. The code above is only hard coded for a 2x2xajdacency matrix. Write your code dynamically so it will work for any N.  You need a nested for loop that will create all the edges for you. 

Why are you hard coding the size of the array? Try creating the size of the NxN array from the given input of N.

Comment: Thank you Tarique for your comment. I made some small changes to avoid hard coding. Now I can adjust N before the last for-loop starts. The code gives the correct result for N=2, but it gives me the error of "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" for N=3 and higher.

Comment: stop hard coding the add_edges function in the for loop. For a 2x2 matrix you will need 4 add_edge calls (or half that because your add edge actually fills in two cells of the matrix) but this is not the case for when N=3. Instead populate the matrix using a nested for loop. Take a look at how geekforgeeks shows filling the matrix. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implementation-of-dfs-using-adjacency-matrix/